# Keras Estimator + tf.data API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

TF 1.12:

Trying to convert Pre-canned estimator to Keras with tf.keras.layers:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        model_dir='/tmp/keras',
        feature_columns=deep_columns,
        hidden_units = [100, 75, 50, 25],
        config=run_config)
```

to a Keras model using tf.keras.layers:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(14,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(75))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model, model_dir='/tmp/keras', config=run_config)
```

When I run the Keras model I get:

```
for n in range(40 // 2):
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
    results = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

    # Display evaluation metrics
    tf.logging.info('Results at epoch %d / %d', (n + 1) * 2, 40)
    tf.logging.info('-' * 60)
```

When I train it I get this error:

Main code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/census_main.py

> KeyError: "The dictionary passed into features does not have the
>   expected inputs keys defined in the keras model.\n\tExpected keys:
>   {'dense_50_input'}\n\tfeatures keys: {'workclass', 'occupation',
>   'hours_per_week', 'marital_status', 'relationship', 'race', 'fnlwgt',
>   'education', 'gender', 'capital_loss', 'capital_gain', 'age',
>   'education_num', 'native_country'}\n\tDifference: {'workclass',
>   'occupation', 'hours_per_week', 'marital_status', 'relationship',
>   'dense_50_input', 'race', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'gender',
>   'capital_loss', 'capital_gain', 'age', 'education_num',
>   'native_country'}"

This is my input_fn:

```
def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
  assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), (
      '%s not found. Please make sure you have run census_dataset.py and '
      'set the --data_dir argument to the correct path.' % data_file)

  def parse_csv(value):
    tf.logging.info('Parsing {}'.format(data_file))
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('income_bracket')
    classes = tf.equal(labels, '>50K')  # binary classification
    return features, classes

  # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)

  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_NUM_EXAMPLES['train'])

  dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=5)

  # We call repeat after shuffling, rather than before, to prevent separate
  # epochs from blending together.
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  return dataset

def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(train_file, 2, True, 40)

def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(test_file, 1, False, 40)
```

Comment: Did you use ```model.fit(train_x, train_y)``` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Nop, I'm using estimator.train directly, isn't this the purpose of model_to_estimator function?

Comment: You have  input_shape=(10,), but you pass 14 feature and the model expect the same, why?

Comment: thanks for replying, corrected it, update the error now. In the canned estimator I pass the features I'm interested: feature_columns=deep_columns, just not sure how to tell Keras to pass the same?

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to check if you were able to find a solution to this, as I am facing the same problem - I'm trying to use a keras estimator and build the appropriate data input function so that i can use tf.train_and_evaluate() and deploy a custom keras model on google cloud ml.

Comment: Yes, I did. I will post the answer

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/tf-keras-census/census/tf-keras/trainer/model.py

Comment: @spicyramen You did not end up using `model_to_estimator` as far as I can tell in the sample code you linked?

Comment: @MaxPower that is correct, they added tf.data support to Keras and end up using that API.

Comment: did you find out a solution, I'm getting the same problem....

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an input layer:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=your_tensor_shape, name=your_feature_key))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu))
```